# How firebase functions identifies the app deployed them, if there are more than one apps in the firebase project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

I have firebase project in which it has 5 apps.So I have deployed firebase functions from two apps , for notifications between them, and now **I have changed the package name of one of the apps that deployed the functions, so added a new app to the same firebase project and downloaded new google-services.json and added it to the flutter project in the Android studio**. My question is how is it possible that even now after changing and completely new google-services.json, firebase functions are working for the app. And

1. **how they are identifying that they belong to this app?**
2. **What happens to google-services.json file if I delete the all the other apps in the firebase project except these two apps,as some information about these apps are stored in google-services.json file?**

**P.S: Suggest an edit if there's anything wrong with the question**

*Thanks for the help in advance :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Function are deployed to a project, and not to a specific application within that project.

So if you're using callable Cloud Functions, the client-side SDK just reads the project details from the `google-services.json`. It does not use app-specific configuration data.

But if you have have two apps within a project, the FCM tokens for those apps are going to be different. So you can target the users of a specific app based on their unique tokens.

Comment: Thanks  Frank for the reply, in my case, I have changed the package name or application Id and downloaded the new google-services.json file as the new app and added it to the existing flutter project, am I doing correct?

Comment: And can I delete the other apps from the project, except for those two apps and this does not effect the other google-services.json files of these two apps, as google-services.json files have some information about the other apps too

Comment: If you've renamed the package, you'll probably indeed want to remove the previous app definition fro your project once you no longer have users on the app with the old package name.